# weblogic 12.2.1 LDAP Security Provider for Authentication and DBMS for Authorization

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, weblogic, wildfly

I'm migrating some Java EE 7 apps that uses the simple Java EE security model. I'd like to know if it's possible to configure Authentication against an external LDAP Server and Authorization using a Database Table in WLS 12.2.1. I was able to do that in wildfly 8.2.0.Final using a combination of the [password-stacking](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Using_JBoss_Login_Modules-Password_Stacking.html) option on the LdapExtended and the UserRoles login modules.

So far in WLS, I have configured without any issue the external LDAP authentication provider and also the DBMS auth provider. I put the JAAS flag to Optional on both of them and order my LDAP provider before my RDBMS provider. In the console, I can see my user list coming from the ldap provider and the group coming from the rdbms one. I deployed a very simple Java EE with Basic auth security enabled and I can authenticate but I fail the authorization step. Before providing more detail on my config, I'd like to know if this kind of configuration is possible with WLS. I'm under the impression that the LDAP provider does not pass the authenticated principal to the DBMS for group validation.

Comment: Found a solution for this?

Comment: No went with ldap only for both authentication and autorization